# GSON exclusionStrategy shouldSkipField need to know field's concrete class

Tags: java, gson

I am having trouble with GSON exclusionStrategy implemenation.I need to implement GSON serialization filtering based on template. in GSON. in GSON exclusionStrategy , shouldSkipField , I need to know field's concrete class, where am I in class hierarchy

My class structure is as following:-

```
class A{ 
        String id; 
} 

class B{ 
        String bb; 
        String bbb; 
} 

class c extends A{ 
       String cVal; 
       B bObj; 
}
```

I want to access 'id' field via class c, but id field's declaring class comes as A instead of c.

Thanks in advance, 
Preeti

Comment: what's your exclusionStrategy code ? Your problem seems to be Java reflection and not a Gson one.